# MS GraphAPI Drives Create new folder

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I need help with Microsoft GraphAPI.
I want to create folder in SharePoint Online Site Collection, in Document Library, but i get Error.

I Have Site Collection, name A,
in this Site Collection i have Document Library, name XY
I have tried to create Folder using this

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_post_children?view=odsp-graph-online

But i always get error, 400 Bad Request.

```
.../v1.0/sites/tenantName,1a2b3f27-0d23-4b68-8e71-fe06cbfed6b4,5e911195-1934-42a3-814c-86ab8ec2699c/drive/items/b!Jz8rGiMNaEuOcf4Gy_7WtJURkV40GaNCgUyGq47CaZwdNH0_zurqQ6XWJreCPMnF/children";
```

> Error message is, "The expression is not valid".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using driveId as the parent-item-id. The parent-item-id looks like `01KC572RLYVJZL5JE4ANCLOTQKQMIKYVHL`

You can get the parent-item-id by using

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/children
```

If you get nothing from this request, you should create a folder under the root directory first.

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/children

{
  "name": "New Folder222",
  "folder": { },
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank for your help. I tried it, but i don't get any value back,  {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('.....%2C1a2b3f27-0d23-4b68-8e71-fe06cbfed6b4%2C5e911195-1934-42a3-814c-86ab8ec2699c')/drive/root/children",
    "value": []
}

Comment: @MatjažReberc If so, you should create the folder in the root first by using `POST /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/children`

Comment: @MatjažReberc You can use the graph explorer to test the apis. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: I did this, it works, but i want to create folder in some other DocumetLibrary, not root.

Comment: @MatjažReberc I see. Then you should use `POST /sites/{site-id}/drives/driveId/root/children`  This will navicate to the root directory of the DocumentLibrary.